# How to show the value of my tag when I click it?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
 <Button
android:id="@+id/On"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
android:text="Prender"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
<tag android:id="@+id/on_tag" android:value="1" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/Off"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:tag="0"
    android:text="Apagar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/On"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="143dp"
    <tag android:id="@+id/on_tag2" android:value="0" />
```

How can I show the value of my tag when I click it? I want to create onClick event to see the value 0 or 1 "I want an INT value" not string

It's the same if I use

```
android:id="@+id/Off"
android:value="1"
```

or

```
<tag android:id="@+id/On" android:value="1" />
```

This is the .kt I'm using kotlin and need to show the int value of the tag

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onClick(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.this)

        On.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { v ->
            Log.e(
                FragmentActivity.TAG,
                v.getTag(R.id.on_tag)?.toString()
            )
        })

        Off.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { v ->
            Log.e(
                FragmentActivity.TAG,
                v.getTag(R.id.on_tag2)?.toString()
            )
        })


    }


}
```

Comment: It's a tag that gives the button a value but I need to show the value on onClick event

Comment: This xml is incorrect. make sure this works in layout designer first

Comment: I guess tag attribute of view - `android:tag="value"` assigns tag value to that view.  Which can be used to findViewByTags. Kindly search accordingly. I do not know about <tag>, will look into it.

Comment: Yes I just saw that method android:tag="value" it's the same as <tag> but how can I create the onClick method to show the value of the tag?

Comment: @PankajKumar Kindly validate the answer.

Comment: Also onClick has been replaced with onCreate. I hope you understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `onClick(View v)` you can call `v.getTag()` as follows

```
 Button btnOn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.On);
 btnOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e(TAG,String.valueOf(v.getTag())); 
            }
        });
```

But for above code to work you xml should be as follows.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/On"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
    android:text="Prender"
    android:tag="1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Off"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
/>
```

**I did some research and trial Updating answer based on question and your xml - Also correcting it**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/On"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
    android:text="Prender"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Off"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
<tag android:id="@+id/on_tag" android:value="1" />
</Button>
```

Just small change in getTag() instead `view.getTag()` will pass id as below.

```
btnOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.e(TAG,String.valueOf(v.getTag(R.id.on_tag))); 
                }
            });
```

> In updated answer i.e tag as separate, we can have multiple Tag value
>   assigned to a view. Sorry I forgot about tag because never
>   used much, I generally set tag to view during run time only. but thanks to you and
>   [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#tags)

Kotlin code for same as below

```
 On.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { v ->
            Log.e(
                FragmentActivity.TAG,
                v.getTag(R.id.on_tag)?.toString()
            )
        })
```

As I have used `on_tag` in `id` for `tag`. Also what you need is String, while getTag returns Object so converting it to string.

Comment: Give me few minutes I will convert it Kotlin

Comment: I'm using kotlin and it insta converts the code now it's like this `On.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { v ->
                Log.e(
                    FragmentActivity.TAG,
                    v.getTag(R.id.on_tag).toString()
                )
            })`  But it has some errors here "Unresolved reference Log" and the same on "on_tag"

Comment: We have the same problem - Unresolved reference: Log and on_tag

Comment: @JorgeAlberto what is the id you have used?. Kindly look in my xml id assigned to my on button view is `On` while id assigned to it's tag is on_tag please check properly in your xml and kotlin code properly.

Comment: @JorgeAlberto Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205286/discussion-between-shadow-droid-and-jorgealberto).

Comment: @PankajKumar Thank you. But if you look updated question, It seems there is more things to fix.

Comment: If your are talking about to get int, that is not a big deal. GetTag returns Object which can be casted to Integer. He just need to handle exception

Comment: @PankajKumar no I was referring to something else check discussion you will understand :)